# PHP - delegating tasks to executables

Tags: php, linux, executable, server-side

In the application I've written there is a whole class that only takes in some parameters, eventually fetches the db for other parameters, and then returns the results to the asking class. It only handles data, so it would be perfect to "outsurce" those functions to something more efficient than PHP.

I've read the official php faq page on ["PHP and COM"](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.com.php), and seen that it is not possible to run a precompiled dll from php.

So, do you think it is possible and worth to do it with some other methods? And how would you do it?

Maybe [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/index.php) / [RESTful WS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html) could do, but still java does not sound like the best option ([according to this post it's "clunky"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203055/php-java-bridge-vs-restful-webservice-with-regards-to-performance-which-is-bet))

HipHop would be a great solution, but as of now it's way too early to use it in production for my needs.

All the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable) seem to be aimed at creating an .exe file for making a standalone win app, whereas my app is hosted on a centOS server and I haven o need to port it to windows (or at least that's not my intention right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use C++ and RabbitMQ to tie it together. I've also had success, when there wasn't much of a scope for the project, at using Redis as a tie in.

Can't say enough good things about using a message bus to separate processes (like RabbitMQ).

If you're just getting started with RabbitMQ, I'd highly recommend [RabbitMQ in Action](http://www.manning.com/videla/).

You don't have to use C++ though. That's one of the major benefits of using message buses; you can substitute later, if need be (and the API stays the same). Here are a list of clients that can receive and post messages to RabbitMQ: http://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html

Insert favorite, high-performance language here.